# how to use gem5 helper function

Tags: helpfile

I am trying to run ARM power model explained in learning gem5 tutorials from:

https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part2/arm_power_modelling/

How can I use gem5 helper function that mentioned many times in learning gem5 tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "helper function" isn't a feature of gem5, but basically a type of function, or the purpose you write a function for. Take for example this quote from the tutorial you linked:

> The provided `fs_power.py` script extends the existing `fs_bigLITTLE.py` script by importing it and then modifying the values. As part of this, several loops are used to iterate through the descendants of the SimObjects to apply the Power Models to. So to extend an existing simulation to support power models, it can be helpful to define a helper function which does this:

And after this, there's the definition of the helper function in this case, being `_apply_pm`.

So a helper function is just a "normal" function that you write in addition to your main code. The helper function (often you have multiple helper functions) doesn't do your main task, but something to, well, help with it ;) In the case quoted above, the function `_apply_pm` doesn't do a simulation itself, but it extends an existing simulation to support power models.

This isn't specific to gem5. You'll find the idea of writing code to do "side tasks" in many, many places, being it helper functions, helper classes or whatever the technology in question uses.